# Python - Save the context

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I need to save the context of the program before exiting ... I've put all the needed stuff to an object that I've previously created a I tried many times to picke it, but no way !!
I continuously have errors like :

- PicklingError: Can't pickle 'SRE_Match' object: <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x2a969cd9c0>
- OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: [the file that I am referencing is rwx for all]

the code that I use is :

```
f = open ("/xxxx/yyyy/toto/titi/important_stuff//impo/tmp/contest.obj", 'w').close()
os.chmod("/xxxx/yyyy/toto/titi/important_stuff//impo/tmp/contest.obj", 0777)
f = open ("/xxxx/yyyy/toto/titi/important_stuff//impo/tmp/contest.obj", 'w')
pickle.dump(useCaseList, f)
```

Any knows how can I solve these problems or has another solution ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are perhaps referring to context, and not contest?

Comment: your OSError prob refers to os.chmod

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand why ... the permissions are

-rwxrwxrwx  1 amuharem com_upr_gcc_gco_dev 723 May  6 10:11 contest.obj

the only thing that differs is the author !

Comment: Some objects can't be pickled, so you just have to pickle another object.

Comment: I am tring the whole morning to pickle different objects that I have created but there is now way ! I succeeded to pickle the same object while empty, but after I "fill" it i got the "can't pickle message"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the python doc [What can be pickled and unpickled](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled). You have objects that can not be pickled.

Comment: From the FAQ: 
    No question is too trivial or too "newbie". Oh yes, and it should be about programming. You know, with a computer.

Comment: God it's amazing how easy it is to find people on the Internets so willing to yell at people trying to learn.